# How to find the distance if the points are above Earth's surface?

Tags: navigation, flight-planning

There is a lot of information online about how to find the distance between two points if both the points are on the surface of the earth. But no article mentions about how to find the distance if both the points are above earth surface. Haversine formula works only for the points that are on the earth surface. But what about points that are above earth surface?

Note: I think we should consider the curvature of the earth as well while computing the distance.

Comment: I think this question would be better served on Gis.SE. I'll wait for some others to have a look at it, but in case I will move it there.

Comment: @J.Dow: why do you think Haversine formula works only if the points are on the **earth**'s surface?!?! It works for any sphere. Just use the right value for the radius.

Comment: @Curd Yes you are right. It works for any sphere. I was just considering the context of finding distance between two points above earth surface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Earth's mean radius being 6,371 km, adding 10 km to that adds about 0.15% to the geometric distance at 10 km altitude. But since you have tagged it [flight-planning](/questions/tagged/flight-planning), the difference is very small that you can neglect.

Since the atmosphere moves with the Earth, TAS ≈ GS in no wind is good enough for the altitudes where planes operate.

However, for a very accurate air distance, use a radius based on the altitude in the [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula). But if such high accuracy is needed, you also need to consider the exact Earth's radius at the point of measurement as it [varies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_radius#Location-dependent_radii) from 6,353 to 6,384 km. You also need to consider the true altitude as a height above the geodesic, and not just a pressure altitude.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75940/discussion-on-answer-by-ymb1-how-to-find-the-distance-if-the-points-are-above-ea).